# How to speedup binary transformation from integer values

Tags: python, python-2.7

I wrote the following method (in python 2.7) that generates a set of integers and transform them into binary representation. It takes self-explanatory two parameters: `total_num_nodes` and `dim`. It returns numpy matrix-like containing the binary representation of all these integers:

```
def generate(total_num_nodes, dim):

    # Generate random nodes from the range (0, dim-1) 
    nodes_matrix = [random.randint(0, 2 ** dim - 1) for _ in range(total_num_nodes)]

    # Removes duplicates
    nodes_matrix = list(set(nodes_matrix))

    # Transforms each node from decimal to string representation
    nodes_matrix = [('{0:0' + str(dim) + 'b}').format(x) for x in nodes_matrix]

    # Transforms each bit into an integer.
    nodes_matrix = np.asarray([list(map(int, list(x))) for x in nodes_matrix], dtype=np.uint8)

    return nodes_matrix
```

The problem is that when I pass very large values, say `total_num_nodes= 10,000,000` and `dim=128`, the generation time takes really long time. A friend of mine hinted me that the following line is actually a bottleneck and it is likely to be responsible for the majority of computation time:

```
# Transforms each node from decimal to string representation
nodes_matrix = [('{0:0' + str(dim) + 'b}').format(x) for x in nodes_matrix]
```

I cannot think of other faster method that can replce this line so that I get to speedup the generation time when it is running on a single processor. Any suggestion from you is really really appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Instead of guessing, why don't you try benchmarking the program?\

Comment: [Unfortunately your guess seems to be wrong](https://tio.run/##pY/LTsMwEEX3/orZZVzSKOkKUfVLoioyjQGL@CF7KiWq@PYwTlhURV0UvLHnce/1CRN9eLebZ2ODjwTubMMEKoEL4qdFxuoSonK9t0KQJzV0vNY53@sEB2jqfERv7FrwDj@yqjoN/vSJUohlt7OKohl52K5uVb6MI6xL2MFmA9ljC42ENx@hA@Ny7LvGm1B5FNTcZOwhxGzFgy0Ql8snml/Rg0mESRNe96X8u2GLxaV@qQt4gkQRGUHys3j9KmTFGLyH4wo0ZqBr9T8wXKhUUjGqCdsFyaqALCxXQCa6l1lCT1PQB3Y4s@D5AfR5/gY).

Comment: @user202729 Thank you very much for this. I never thought about that. I am still a bit intermediate programmer. I am surprised that the mapping is line that takes the majority of time!!!

Comment: I will write a complete answer later. For now, a hint (verified on TIO): Use `ord`.

Comment: @user202729 Thank you very much. I cannot wait to see your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it all in numpy and it will be faster.

The following generates `total_num_nodes` rows of `dim` columns of `np.uint8` data, then keeps the unique rows by providing a view of the data suitable for `np.unique`, then translating back to a 2D array:

```
import numpy as np

def generate(total_num_nodes, dim):
    a = np.random.choice(np.array([0,1],dtype=np.uint8),size=(total_num_nodes,dim))
    dtype = a.dtype.descr * dim
    temp = a.view(dtype)
    uniq = np.unique(temp)
    return uniq.view(a.dtype).reshape(-1,dim)
```

Comment: Impressive! Thank you so so much

Comment: My method is slower anyway (about 2.5x), so I won't post. ( @Lauren) (using `a != '0'` seems to be slightly faster than `ord(a) - 48`)